# XQIB XQuery - error when trying to 'let' a variable

Tags: xquery

My XQuery knowledge is pretty lacking but I'm trying to play around with XQIB (XQuery in the Browser), but even just setting a variable errors

```
let $foo := "bar"
```

...generates the error

```
MXQuery output the following error during compilation:
Line 1, Column 18: err:XPST0003 Error while parsing FFLWOR Expr: 'return' expected!
let $foo := "bar"    ERROR                        
Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
```

I've looked at the samples on the XQIB site, and it seems the `let` statements there are always in sub-routines, e.g. alerts or functions. Is this to suggest that in XQuery, code must always live in a function of sorts, rather than be free-standing?

For example, one of their examples is this, which of course works:

```
b:alert(
    let $x := <a><b>2</b><c>4</c></a>
    return xs:string($x/b * $x/c)
)
```

But this, my altered version, doesn't.

```
let $x := <a><b>2</b><c>4</c></a>
b:alert(
    return xs:string($x/b * $x/c)
)
```

What's up with the latter? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return is at the wrong position:

```
let $x := <a><b>2</b><c>4</c></a>
return
    b:alert(
        xs:string($x/b * $x/c)
    )
```

You only need a `return` if you used some (part of a) flwor-expression. `let` starts one, so you will need `return` after it. As you haven't got one as parameter, you don't need (and neither are allowed) to put a `return` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And what you're describing - that's the rules of FLWOR, presumably, rather than specifically of XQIB or XQuery, right? So I know what to do further reading on.

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to declare a variable then do several actions which reference it, rather than just one return statement? For example in [this XMLPlayground session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/93kjy1), I'm outputting an `<li>` for each character in the XML. What if I wanted to add two `<li>`s per iteration? I tried separating the `insert node` statements with a comma (as I've seen in some XQIB examples) but that errors. Thanks again.

Comment: You can always "return"/run a sequence of updating statements by sending them as a sequence. Try eg. `return (insert node <li>{$i/name}</li> into b:dom()//ul, insert node <li>{$i/name}</li> into b:dom()//ul);`. I guess I overwrote your Playground session, have a look at the running code over there with more readable formatting. By the way, cool site. :)

Comment: Aha I knew it would be something like that. Thanks a lot. (p.s. thanks re: site - just launched it. Very much in beta - any suggestions welcome.)

Comment: I've got it working ([see session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/93kjy1)) but would appreciate any thoughts re: how I've done it. If you had a second to glance at it I'd be grateful, though no problem if busy. Feel free to overwrite the session.

Comment: Looks fine (though I don't really know what you ask me to look at exactly). Sometimes using [element construction](http://www.datadirect.com/resources/dis/xquery-guided-tour/creating-nodes.html) helps gaining readability, especially when building nested tags. Decide yourself. :)